# How can I store items of unkown types using StackExchange.Redis?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am implimenting an existing cache interface (for Redis) within a legacy code base (I am unable to refactor it to be more appropriate), the interface doesn't specify any type information for example:

```
interface ICache {
    object Get(string key);
    void Set(string key, object item);
}
```

With version 1.2 of StackExchange.Core you have to specify the type when storing/retreiving from the database - which I don't have.

Currently I feel like I am hacking around the problem, I store all objects as serialized strings, then use Json.net to Deserialize based on the $type information.

Is there a more appropriate solution to my problem, that doesn't involve changing the interface?

Comment: note: StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Core is not directly affiliated with StackExchange.Redis. In terms of StackExchange.Redis, I'd say simply: serialize your data in any way that is convenient to you, as either a `string` or `byte[]`, and: job done

Answer (score 0):

No that's totally cool. Redis can store values as string or byte array only anyways, at least for normal string or hash.

And if you don't know the type upfront, you have to help yourself and work with a separated field in Redis which stores the value. You use the $type field, Newtonsoft.Json generates I guess? I'm using a separated field on a hash where I store the value, type and other meta information...

When you deserialize the value, you have to know the concrete type, and the only way to know that, is the assembly qualified type information you have stored.

I use the same for http://cachemanager.net.

You can optimize it though. It is not necessary to always serialize an object which actually costs some performance. For scalar values and strings, you could just store the value and the type information within a hash, and cast it, instead of deserializing it. That's what I do at least, and the performance gain is pretty significant. 
That being said, if you store POCOs only anyways, it doesn't matter.